# Como auto detectar o idioma atual do sistema?

Tags: java

```
package linguagem;
import java.util.*;
public class Linguagem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("PORTUGUESE", "PT");
        System.out.println("Linguagem: " + locale.getDisplayLanguage());
    }
}
```

Então ele retorna `portuguese`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, o meu sistema está em inglês, preciso que me retorne `english`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de auto detectar o idioma atual do sistema?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Sempre que tiver tanto o código como uma imagem do código, prefira deixar apenas o código, que é suficiente, desde que formatado corretamente.

Comment: Um detalhe importante é que `new Locale("PORTUGUESE", "PT")` **não** retorna um locale que corresponde ao idioma português. O problema é que o construtor [não valida a entrada e aceita qualquer coisa](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). O correto para português de Portugal é `new Locale("pt", "PT")`

Answer (score 5):

Voce pode usar [`Locale.getDefault();`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault())

Da documentacao:

> ... The Java Virtual Machine sets the default locale
>   during startup based on the host environment....

Em traducao livre:

> A maquina virtual Java obtem a configuracao da localicade no arranque baseado na configuracao do sistema.